# How to change cursor in Ubuntu 11.10 "GNOME Classic"

Tags: 11.10, gnome, cursor

I don't like how the cursor looks when pointing to Web browser links. How can I change it - only this one or the whole cursors theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gnome-tweak-tool. Go to Theme > Cursor Theme